# Check for opening and closing tags with HTML Agility Pack or Regexp?

Tags: c#, html

I have a little Text Editor written in C#.

I need to open HTML files (Already done) in plain text, and check for correct opening and closing tags. For example, if I have this:

`<body> Text </body>` It should say it is correct, but if I have: `<body> <body>` it should say it is wrong.

Any way to get this with HTML Agility Pack or a Regexp in C#?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 8):

```
    public bool IsCorrectHtml(string html)
    {
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
        var parseErrors = htmlDocument.ParseErrors;
        return !parseErrors.Any();  // return true if no error.
    }
```

Comment: is "html" the HTML file I wan to correct? What should I print to tell the error or correct message?

Comment: html is text content of HTML file. As I understood you need to check syntax of HTML. This method returns false if HTML is not correct and true if correct. This code uses htmlagilitypack.

Comment: I think you want to negate your result: `return !parseErrors.Any();`.

Comment: Thanks. Of course !parseErrors.Any().

Comment: Hi, i did not work as expected. I am using this:
if (IsCorrectHtml(Document.Text) == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Good");
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Not Good");

If I have typed a long text into the RichTextBox(Document), it only check for the first and last tag, it does not check for the other tags inside. 

Any help?